# Epson Printer Prints weird Yellow Magenta Cyan ending

Tags: print-production, digital-printing

Based on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118234/which-stack-exchange-website-for-printer-problems) they recommended I post my printer problem here. My Epson L4260 prints this weird output at the end of only glossy photo paper print from Microsoft Word. I tried using the laptop and also the desktop pc both have the same effect. And i made sure I have the latest firmware version. Is this a Microsoft Word problem? Maybe microsoft is sending corrupted image data? Sometimes it works properly with other images. At times when it does not work, it stops moving the paper onwards at the ending part while it is still printing and then when it finishes you have to force pull the paper out. But it always works properly with plain paper.

[image]

So this happens with 260 GSM photo paper. If I use 135 GSM photo paper the problem is reduced to lesser problem

[image]

Comment: Seems like an issue with how the paper advances through the printer. This is more likely to be a limitation issue with your paper and printer rather than a software issue. I have this problem if I use too heavy of paper on my Konica 3070 printer and try to print business cards as 3x8 but works when I reduce the rows to 7. If you reduce the number of rows by 1, does this still happen?

Comment: @AndrewH thank you for your response. hmm that's interesting. i used glossy photo paper gsm 260 on my L4260. And I believe it should support glossy photo paper, but probably just the thinner ones? Now when I tried the sticker photo paper which is a bit thinner at 135gsm it works. Yeah it works if I remove the last row which is my workaround then I just feed the paper in again 180 degrees to print 1 more row to fill the page.

Comment: so people are voting to close my question. I posted it in GSE because that's what they recommended here in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118234/which-stack-exchange-website-for-printer-problems)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Well it might have been the case  ten years ago that this would have been the case. Anyway you should not read anything into close votes untill it gets closed. The primary reason your currently being closed is that this question requires knowledge and setup that is very specific and the circumstances are not in your post. So the reason of closure is lack of information that could be had from your question not the type of question.

Comment: @joojaa thanks for the info. I added more info and now I know its easily reproducible with 260 gsm photo paper. And I noticed the problem reduces as you decrease the paper thickness like 135 GSM so it seems like it really is a limitation as mentioned by AndrewH

Answer (score 2):

I have verified that this seems to be a printer limitation rather than a software limitation as mentioned by AndrewH. As you reduce the GSM thickness of the paper from 260 gsm to 135 gsm, the problem reduces. As a workaround you can eliminate the last row, and after you finish the print, you can turn the paper around and print one more row to finish filling up the entire page.